# Is biopsy still required for cancer diagnosis given that advanced medical imaging is now available?

Tags: tumors, biopsy, cancer

For cancer diagnosis, there is biopsy, an invasive technique. However, [PET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography) CT, [SPECT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_emission_computed_tomography) CT, [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) are non-invasive. Do oncologists still require the use of biopsy to ascertain type of cancer, i.e., to confirm the presence or absence of malignancy? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 3):

In many cases yes, a tumor must be biopsied in order to determine exactly what type of tumor it is. Advanced imaging can, in some cases, diagnose a specific type of tumor. However, there are many chemotherapy agents that are very specific not just to a particular tumor, but a particular tumor with certain genetic factors (such as presence or lack of [specific receptors](https://clincancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/19/19/5505.short)), so it is impossible to plan the best treatment without tissue.

Comment: We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: @CareyGregory There is a paucity of free, open-access literature from which to cite for basic topics such as this. It is possible to cite multiple studies that reference a particular genetic marker, but in general those references are too high-level for this specific question.

Comment: I think a biopsy is usually ordered after these scans. I had PET then CT then biopsy. Chemo and radiation for the cancer, then two years later the routine CT showed something, got a PET and then it was still  necessary for a biopsy  ( MDAnderson-  presumably they know what  is necessary).

Comment: @RudyB I understand and what you added is perfectly sufficient. We don't need a doctoral thesis level of citations, just a basic sanity check or two.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The order depends upon multiple factors. In my practice, I can literally get a CT performed in minutes if I really need to (usually for strokes and traumas), and some days I can get an MRI done within half an hour (but almost always only for stroke or spinal cord compression). Granted, I have not ever ordered a PET-CT, those may take some time to arrange or require travel. Interventional radiology also may take some time and/ or require travel in order to get a biopsy performed (or general surgery, or pulmonology, etc.).

Comment: For the second round ; regular CT showed something, so a few days later the PET was done. Then in a few days the biopsy , cancer had returned to the same location. It was  then removed surgically .